# C program with nested loop to get prime numbers

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

Hello Gurus of programming, I've been learing C programming and I encountered an example in a tutorial to get the list of prime numbers from 2 to 100. but I cannot understand the nested loop condition.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main ()
{ /* local variable definition */ 
    int i, j;

    for(i=2; i<100; i++)
    { 
        for(j=2; j <= (i/j); j++) 
            if(!(i%j))
                break; // if factor found, not prime 
        if(j > (i/j))
            printf("%d is prime\n", i); 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

I don't get the second condition

```
for(j=2; j <= (i/j); j++)
```

also if there is no braces on the nested loop, that means that only the following line after the "for" will be executed, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: `i/j` does an integer division of `i` and `j`. As `j` increases by `1` each loop iteration, the loop will continue as long as `j` does not exceed `i/j`. In other words, there's no point in checking factors of `i` passed the "multiplicative (harmonic) midpoint". On the braces question: the `if(...) break;` is considered one statement, so it will be taken into the `for` loop without the need for braces.

Comment: That's correct, no braces mean it will only execute the following line. So in that second for loop it's only executing the check for if `(i%j) > 0`

Comment: @JohnOdom more specifically, without braces, the loop will execute one following *statement* (a *statement* can be multiple *lines*). It captures the entire `if` statement: `if (!(i&j)) break;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(j=2; j <= (i/j); j++) // efficient way to say j <= square root of i
    if(!(i%j)) break; // if factor found, not prime
```

Starting at 2, and going up to the square root of i, check to see if i is divisible by j.

The reason for this is if no integer less than or equal to the number's square root can evenly divide the number, we know it's not going to match anything bigger.

Think about it.  If we know 17 isn't divisible by 2, 3, or 4, we know it's prime, because to be divisible by two numbers greater than 4, it'd have to be at least 25.

Comment: Just for completeness - it would be clearer to express the condition as `j * j <= i`. The more obscure expression `j <= (i/j)` might be more efficient because one `IDIV` instruction calculates both `i%j` and `i/j`.

Comment: hhmm I see, but for example if J equals 2, then 2 * 2 is 4 and is greater than i=2, so the loop would not execute? because J is greater than i? or am I wrong?

Comment: @user3329896 Yes, the loop would not execute, because `j*j` is greater than `i` or because `j` is greater than `i/j` - both conditions have the same result. A mathematician would say that `j` is greater than `sqrt(i)` - all these conditions are equivalent.

Comment: @anatolyg `j * j <= i` works the same as `j <= (i/j)` for small `j`.  When `i` is near `INT_MAX`, the product `j*j` may exceed INT_MAX and then undesirable results occur.  `j <= (i/j)` does not have this problem.

Comment: @anatolyg but then the Output is:
2 is prime 
3 is prime 
5 is prime 
7 is prime 
11 is prime 
13 is prime 
17 is prime 
19 is prime 
23 is prime
etc...
why is the 2 printed if following the rules when both J and i are 2, the loop would not execute?

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it.  It sounds like you have another issue where you code stops printing out primes after 43?

Comment: right, I double checked the code and I think I got it =) @m24p I've checked the code and it prints the prime numbers until 97

Comment: Oh, I see what your question was.  The inner for loop doesn't run when i=2, but the conditional after that, `if(j > (i/j))`' goes to the true case, because 2 > 2/2.  If your question has been answered sufficiently, please mark it as answered.  :)